# Python 2.7.6 - Reading a certain part of an array

Tags: python, arrays, string, time, indexing

I'm trying to output an index of characters from a string. The string is apart of an array, which is gathered from `f = open('times.txt)`, each line in the the "times.txt" file follows the same layout (dd/mm/yyyy, ss.mm).

I want to only output the last 4 characters as a float, but I'm not sure how to do that. So far I've only managed to output each string from the text document onto a separate line in python, i.e.

```
dd/mm/yyyy, ss.mm
dd/mm/yyyy, ss.mm
dd/mm/yyyy, ss.mm
etc.
```

Here's the code for that:

```
    f = open('times.txt')
lines = f.readlines()

#For loop to force numbers into an individual line
i = 0
for i in range(0,6):
    print lines[i] + ""
#This code is under construction.
def TimeSorter():
    global i
    if i in lines.len(13,17):
        if lines.len(13,17)(i) > 0:
            print lines.len(13,17)

f.close()
```

I only want it to print like the following:

```
ss.mm
ss.mm
ss.mm
etc.
```

Comment: The code after "#This Code is under construction" is the code that I was trying to use to accomplish what I want, but it did nothing.

Comment: I think you meant `list`, an [`array`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) is something entirely different in Python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry about that, it's what I've been told in A-level computing from my teacher, he didn't really distinguish the two I guesss

Comment: Outside of Python, the term `array` is often used, but in context of languages that use strict typing and you cannot put more than one type of value into the arrays. A Python list can hold any type of object, while the `array.array` type is strictly type restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hardcode the character slices. Just split over the `,` separating the date from the time:

```
with open('so.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        time = float(line.split(', ')[1])
        print time
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for, thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

The format you're describing is a *comma separated values* file. Fortunately, python comes with a [module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to parse that with:

```
import csv
with open('times.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for date_, time_ in reader:
        t = float(time_)
        # do something with t here
        print t # <-- for example
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('times.txt')                             
lines = f.readlines()                             

#For loop to force numbers into an individual line
for line in lines:                                
    print float(line.split(',')[1])
```

As nooodl said, using the split method is definitely the easiest way to approach the problem. I've used your code to show how this would work.